# Another way to say "will particpate in?"

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I'm trying to say that someone will be participating in a golf event.

Steve Jones **will be participating in the PGA..... **

Comment: As a player, caddy, official? Different terms for different roles.

Comment: it's a tv special about club professionals.

Comment: Does that mean the club professionals will be players? If so,why not *playing*?

Comment: Will **involve** in the...

Comment: Needs more context, as others have stated, but "Competing"?

Answer (score 1):

'Take part in' would be my go-to alternative. This brings the same connotation that 'participating in' has, in that it assumes you will be directly involved in the event/activity, instead of just spectating.

Referring to the comments above 'take part in' could apply to a player, caddy, and official. If you wanted to specify a supporting role such as a caddy or official, you could also use 'helping out in' or simply 'supporting in'.

Any additional information might help us find the more specific term.